# SpriteKit - RotateToAngle

Tags: rotation, sprite-kit, skaction

I have an object that I want it to constantly rotate right & left:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

// I start it facing left side
    object.zRotation = CGFloat(M_PI / 4)
}

 override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */


        let rotateRight = SKAction.rotateToAngle(CGFloat(-M_PI / 4), duration: 2)
        let rotateLeft = SKAction.rotateToAngle(CGFloat(M_PI / 4), duration: 2)

        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([rotateRight, rotateLeft])

        object.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence))
    }
```

The problem is, it only rotates to the right side then it stops completely, it never rotates left and repeate as it should.

Comment: Move the rotation code to `didMoveToView`. It doesn't belong in `update()`.

Comment: That worked, thanks. I guess in update it keeps getting called over and over, how did I miss that?! :(